# Package org.languagetool.language.BritishEnglish does not exist

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, languagetool

I am LanguageTools to implement a spell corrector. I am currently trying to run the example code which checks for basic spelling error in a string. I downloaded and imported languagetool-core-2.2.jar into my project library in Netbeans.

My imports are:

```
import org.languagetool.JLanguageTool;
import org.languagetool.language.BritishEnglish;
import org.languagetool.rules.RuleMatch;
```

My code is this:

```
JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool(new BritishEnglish());
for (Rule rule : langTool.getAllRules()) {
    if (!rule.isSpellingRule()) {
        langTool.disableRule(rule.getId());
    }
}

List<RuleMatch> matches = langTool.check("A speling error");
for (RuleMatch match : matches) {
    System.out.println("Potential typo at line " + match.getLine() + ", column " + match.getColumn() + ": " + match.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Suggested correction(s): " + match.getSuggestedReplacements());
}
```

I am not getting any import errors for my first and third import but I am getting the error "Cannot find symbol: BritishEnglish" for my second import.

After getting frustrated for several hours trying to find a perfectly working .jar containing all the required packages, I have given up.

Could you please point me to a working .jar which will resolve the import errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single JAR that contains everything you need. We (the LanguageTool) developers recommend using Maven or Gradle to manage the dependencies, as documented at http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api.

Also, LanguageTool 2.2 is really old, we're currently at 4.1.

Comment: I initially used 4.1 and had more problems with it than 2.2. And you're right, I had to manually download different versions and pick different stuff from different places to make it work, but still couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

let's try to run a jar file with library:

```
java -cp YOUR_FILE_JAR.jar:libs/* com.yourpakage.Main
```

YOUR_FILE_JAR.jar is your jar file 
libs/* is a path to your dependency JARs. Normally, it's the same folder with the jar file 
com.yourpakage.Main is the class has the main(String[]) method

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There's no class file with the name com.languagetool.Main in the languagetool library that I have downloaded. In fact there no Main class files in the library.

Answer (score 0):

I use maven, and found this issue that might be related:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/languagetool/Languages
    at com.mycompany.app.App.main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.languagetool.Languages
```

I put this in the pom file:

```
 <properties>
    <exec.mainClass>com.mycompany.app.App</exec.mainClass>
 </properties>
```

Then execute the project through maven:

```
$ mvn clean compile
$ mvn exec:java
```